# Elegantly move a UIView to a keyboard's inputAccessoryView

Tags: ios, uiview, uitextfield, uianimation, inputaccessoryview

Is there an elegant way to seamlessly move a `UIView` (i.e. a `UIButton`), that lives on the bottom of it's parent view, to a keyboard's `inputAccessoryView`?

I envision the keyboard to basically pick up the button and drag it up while it is sliding in. Please see the the mock-up below. Obviously, I'd like this to work the other way around as well.

I know how to do both separately, but I have no idea how to combine it. Anyone out there who did that before?

Thanks!

[image: Illustration of the idea]

Update: I forgot to mention that I'm mainly working in the context of `UIScrollViews`. While André's answer below works fine for ordinary views, it breaks when using it with scroll views.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in this case you could ignore using the inputaccessoryview and instead adjust the sign in button's bottom constraint on keyboard notifications.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
  @IBOutlet weak var signInButtonBottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillShow:"), name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillHide:"), name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil)
  }

  func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    let userInfo = notification.userInfo!

    let animationDuration = userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as! Double
    let keyboardEndFrame = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).CGRectValue()

    signInButtonBottomConstraint.constant = keyboardEndFrame.height
    UIView.animateWithDuration(animationDuration) { () -> Void in
      self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
  }

  func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    let userInfo = notification.userInfo!

    let animationDuration = userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as! Double

    signInButtonBottomConstraint.constant = 0.0
    UIView.animateWithDuration(animationDuration) { () -> Void in
      self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, André! That works just fine as long as I use ordinary views. I forgot to mention in my post that I'm mainly use scroll views, in which case this approach does not work anymore. The button then scrolls with the content.

Comment: and what if you exclude the button from the scrollview?

Comment: Oh yeah, right. I think that would work. It would just let me scroll my content underneath the button when the keyboard is hidden. But I'm not sure that would be a problem. Will definitely try that tomorrow. I'll let you know how that went. Thanks again!

Comment: you can simply set your scrollviews bottom contentinset to be the height of the sign in button. :)